# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CFD' with unique index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, key

I am running into an error on the insertion of a single row into a table, dbo.CFD. The complete error states:

Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CFD' with unique index 'IX_CFD_NRSC_FXTR_N'. The duplicate key value is (BP2001, 1990, CHK, 01, 3456).

Looking at the index in question, IX_CFD_NRSC_FXTR_N, it is a non-unique, non-clustered index on a single column (The column with BP2001 in the error).

Looking at the data, there are many records with the values of BP2001, CHK, 01, and 3456, however none with 1990 (but various other values), so it doesn't seem I am conflicting with a unique constraint.

I also verified that all foreign key constraints are being met and the primary key constraint is not being violated.

How can I figure out what exactly is causing this issue? Every example I can find results in there being duplicate data being inserted, but I don't think that is the issue here. Thanks!

Edit----------

The table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CFD](
    [PRPSL_I] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FILE_TYPE_C] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [CAD_FLR_C] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [FXTR_SERL_I] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ADJC_I] [int] NULL,
    [CMP_I] [int] NULL,
    [VER_I] [int] NULL,
    [NRSC_FXTR_N] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [MDSE_SPCE_HT_I] [int] NULL,
    [MDSE_SPCE_LGTH_I] [int] NULL,
    [MDSE_SPCE_DPT_I] [int] NULL,
    [NRSC_FXTR_SIDE_I] [int] NULL,
    [NRSC_FXTR_SECT_I] [int] NULL,
    [BOFM_INCL_F] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DIVI_I] [int] NULL,
    [PRTY_I] [int] NULL,
    [REUSE_I] [int] NULL,
    [FXTR_ISTL_LOC_N] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [PHYS_SECT_NUM_I] [int] NULL,
    [SAFL_LOC_N] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [SEQ_I] [int] NULL,
    [SIDE_ASLE_I] [int] NULL,
    [LDIN_I] [int] NULL,
    [LDIN_STAT_I] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CFD] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PRPSL_I] ASC,
    [FILE_TYPE_C] ASC,
    [CAD_FLR_C] ASC,
    [FXTR_SERL_I] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_CFD_BOFM_INCL_F]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [BOFM_INCL_F]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK1_CFD] FOREIGN KEY([PRPSL_I], [FILE_TYPE_C], [CAD_FLR_C])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CAD_FILE] ([PRPSL_I], [FILE_TYPE_C], [CAD_FLR_C])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK1_CFD]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK2_CFD] FOREIGN KEY([CMP_I])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CMP] ([CMP_I])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK2_CFD]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK3_CFD] FOREIGN KEY([ADJC_I])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ADJC_E] ([ADJC_I])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK3_CFD]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_CFD] CHECK  (([FILE_TYPE_C]<>'SFP'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CFD] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_CFD]
GO



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CFD_NRSC_FXTR_N] ON [dbo].[CFD]
(
    [NRSC_FXTR_N] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Without seeing the table structure (and unique index) it is pretty tough to help here. From what you posted you have violated the constraints in IX_CFD_NRSC_FXTR_N

Comment: @SeanLange Ok, thanks. How do I view the "constraints" of IX_CFD_NRSC_FXTR_N? All I can see is that it is a non-clustered index on a single column. How can I provide more information that would be helpful?

Comment: SQL Server is usually correct about these things. Pls double-check if you're hitting the correct database on the correct server first. If you are, I'd run DBCC CHECKDB then..

Comment: If everything is as you say, then the error message cannot be accurately describing the problem.  Are there *any* unique indexes or uniqueness constraints on the table in question, including a primary key, that the new row could be violating?

Comment: The table structure and index definition.

Comment: I added the table create script. Thanks!

Comment: The error message and the script you provided simply don't match. The error has 4 columns and the index you posted has 1. BTW, does your database come with a decoder ring for all the developers? Everything is so cryptic! And sticking a suffix on a column to indicate the datatype is a horrible practice. What happens when the datatype changes?

Comment: exec EXEC sp_helpindex 'IX_CFD_NRSC_FXTR_N' -- will give details about index.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the laugh. In fact our company does provide a decoder, I wish I was joking. I would never create tables like this if I had a choice.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits That resulted in an error saying 'The object does not exist in the database or is invalid for this operation'.

Comment: Sorry its exec EXEC sp_helpindex 'tablename' so it should be exec sp_helpindex 'dbo.CFD'

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits That worked. According to the output: 'nonclustered located on PRIMARY',  'NRSC_FXTR_N'.